# Extracting web page with jquery content data

Tags: java, jquery, html, dom, jsoup

I need to extract data from particular websites, say it a comment section in a website. What i already tried is extracting html text using jsoup, but since the comment section used jquery it only extract the jquery code not the comments text. Any suggest to solve my problems? thankyou

Comment: Why don't you use an xsl transformation for such purpose?

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTMLUnit to render the page with all needed content and then extract data from build DOMTree. [Here](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/faq.html#AJAXDoesNotWork) you can find info on what to do if AJAX doesn't work OOTB.

Comment: lead me to this bro : Cannot locate declared field class org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.sslContext

Comment: thankyou bro it worked. now i gotta solve my first problem

Comment: Now you need to wait until comments section is rendered and extract data from it.

Comment: there's so much error while rendering every single javascripts dude, even when i set ThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false) and ThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false) it just catch the error also the code won't showing result of js

Comment: Are there also js exceptions when you render it in real browser?